# Mirth to unpretty-print outbound XML

Tags: xml, pretty-print, mirth

I have a Mirth channel that handles huge XML messages, and essentially just routes them to some of our customers without doing too much manipulation on them. Is there a way I can "unpretty" these messages, so as to compress them a little bit? They're often so large that I'm getting heap memory size errors.

(I realize a better workaround is making the message an attachment, but we do some small transformation, and don't know how to do this transformation if the message is an attachment)

Comment: What percentage file size saving are you expecting this to achieve?

Comment: I'm hoping for 10-20%

Comment: Have you tried to increase the default JVM heap size by configuring the administrator.maxheapsize setting?